# Seasonality and period of a non stationary time series

Tags: python, testing, time-series, partial, autocorrelation

So I have a non stationary time series that is hourly, daily and monthly recorded for a year, like this:

```
Hours
2020-01-01 00:00:00     4.0
2020-01-01 01:00:00     3.0
2020-01-01 02:00:00     4.0
2020-01-01 03:00:00     4.0
2020-01-01 04:00:00    14.0
                       ... 
2020-12-31 19:00:00    60.0
2020-12-31 20:00:00    59.0
2020-12-31 21:00:00    72.0
2020-12-31 22:00:00    70.0
2020-12-31 23:00:00    68.0
```

And I have the ACF and PACF plots for the serie.

[ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsB0i.png)

and

[PACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOaZr.png)

Looking at the acf test I can see big pikes at lags=24,48,72. Does that mean that I have a period of 24 hours, or a seasonality of 24 h?

Also, I applied the the Ljung-Box test and for every lag I obtain a p value of 0, which means that my values are showing dependence on each other. I also don´t understand what is the meaning of this test in terms of seasonality.

With this done I need to know what is the period and seasonality of this time serie but I am confused. Need help.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to include screenshot in body of question with Ctrl+V instead of a link.

Comment: I cannot edit in any other way. Sorry